# Why won't this C# database application with parameterized sql work?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, parameters

I have C# forms application with a TextBox called ageTextBox;

After I press a button, the application should update one or more values from my MySQL database, but it doesn't.

Here's the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this works perfectly if I put an actual number instead of @ag
        string sql = "update persons set age = 30 where age = @ag";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ag", OdbcType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@ag"].Value = ageTextBox.Text;
        int aff = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (aff == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("No rows afected");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Everything went as planned");
        }
    }
```

It always shows "No rows affected"! (unless I enter something that's not a number, in which case, an exception is thrown)

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Try using `Convert.ToInt(ageTextBox.Text)` on the Value line. It's possible that MySQL is choking because you're passing it a string and not an int.

Comment: @MichaelTodd add that as an answer; looks convincing

Comment: @MichaelTodd I've tried int.parse and Convert.ToInt... Still not working... Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: I remember a scenario previously where suppling a string arg when comparing against a numeric column would actually perform a string comparison (i.e. MySQL will convert the column to a string value).

Comment: Ignoring the returned rowcount, did the row(s) actually get changed in MySQL?

Comment: silly question; did the data get updated? is it possible that it isn't working any more **because** it is already updated (i.e. not "12" or whatever)

Comment: @p.campbell They don't get updated. I check the MySQL database from its command line after every run of the application.

Comment: I noticed that you are using a named parameter.  I don't think the Odbc provider supports named parameters.  Try chaning the @ag to a question mark.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway You're right. That's the solution. I just had to put a question mark instead of "@ag". Well, I also had to change cmd.Parameters.Add("@ag", OdbcType.Int) to cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", OdbcType.Int) beacause age is the actual name of the column. But basically, I needed a placeholder. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

`cmd.Parameters.Add` is obsolete you should use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` try using this instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ag", int.Parse(ageTextBox.Text));
```

Comment: Should really supply an actual numeric argument.

Comment: And please make sure you're disposing of your connection, command, etc. when you're finished.

Comment: Where is that documented as obsolete? indeed, in many ways AddWithValue is not recommended **in particular** for strings, since it can lead to using variable parameter lengths (causing query plan misses) and getting the db-type wrong (unicode vs ansi, etc). Here's the MSDN page; not obsolete: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dcw81x5.aspx

Comment: Right, I forgot that detail, the actual working code should be `int.Parse(ageTextBox.Text)`.

Comment: Well if he uses cmd.Parameters.Add he will get the following warning: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)

Comment: @Xtian:  using **OdbcCommand** here. You're referencing SqlClient.

Comment: @XtianMacedo that isn't the method he is using, though. It is **only** the `Add(string,object)` that is marked obsolete - not all of `Add(...)`. The overload being used is fine.

Comment: @MarcGravell you're right I didn't notice he was odbc object instead of sqlcommand. Then I think the int.Parse should do the work.

Comment: @conectionist try using this instead `cmd.Parameters["@ag"].Value = int.Parse(ageTextBox.Text);` if that doesn't work try adding the `select @@rowcount` after your statement and use `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` and receive the value.

Comment: @XtianMacedo Ar you suggesting I use this string string sql = "update persons set age = 30 where age = @ag; select @@rowcount"; or execute another command which receives "select @@rowcount" as a parameter ?

Comment: @conectionist Execute `string sql = "update persons set age = 30 where age = @ag; select @@rowcount";`

Comment: @XtianMacedo yeah, that gives me the following error: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.12]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select @@rowcount' at line 1

Comment: @@rowcount doesn't exist anywhere in MySQL.

Comment: @conectionist I think that for MySQL you have to use `select row_count()`

Comment: @XtianMacedo The idea is that if I put more than one instruction in the string (i.e. if it detects a semicolon) it'll generate an exception.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that ODBC isn't reporting rowcounts (the equivalent of `SET NOCOUNT ON`). You might try adding a `select @@rowcount` as a final statement (or the equivalent for your particular DB), and using `ExecuteScalar()` (which will read that value).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but rather a debugging tip. Since you said it works ok when you enter a number in your code, can you try and fire a SQL tracer tool for MySQL (I suppose there is one available somwhere) and see what query is actually executed on the DB in the "working" and in the non working case (and in the exception case maybe)?

This can give you a good insight on what is going on...